# Primefaces:dialog minimizable option not working with modal

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

While enable the minimize option in dialog box with modal as true, then by clicking the minimize, background modal[grey bg] not getting removed. And also, i cannot able to maximize the dialog, which is minimized at the left bottom corner.

I tried using appendtobody, and its not working.

Note:I am using PF 3.4.2

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It was resolved by adding higher z-index to ".ui-dialog-docking-zone".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is a good idea to minimize modal dialogues just because of their nature. Modal dialog says to user stop what are doing now and resolve the issue which is displayed, because it's important. That is why page (or window) under the dialog stays unresponsive, until the task is done. So if I may recommend you, don't use modal dialogues if you need the option to minimize them.