# Primefaces minimizable modal dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, modal-dialog

Maybe I'm missing something obvious - but a minimizable modal dialog doesn't seem to work as intended for me.

Here's what I have:

```
<p:dialog ... modal="true" ... minimizable="true" maximizable="true">
  ...
</p:dialog>
```

This causes a 'minimize' icon to appear at the top of the dialog, but when I try to minimize the dialog, it gets minimized behind the overlay/modal layer, making the minimized item not accessible, thereby not letting me restore it again!

What attribute am I missing? Or is the `minimizable="true"` attribute not meant to be used in combination with the `modal="true"` (I don't see the doc stating that, so just making sure)?

Here's an MCVE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <h:title>Minimizable modal demo</h:title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="resources" name="css/theme.css" />

  <p:separator />

  <p:commandButton value="Show Dialog" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"
    type="button" />

  <p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true"
    minimizable="true" maximizable="true">
    <h:outputText value="This Dialog can be Maximized an Minimized!" />
  </p:dialog>

</h:body>
</html>
```

> Browser: Firefox 37.0
>
> JSF: 2.1.19
>
> PrimeFaces: 5.0
>
> PrimeFacesExtensions: 2.1.0
>
> PrimeFacesTheme: 1.0.8

Comment: What is the advantage of having a minimizable modal dialog? Minimizing makes it only possible to see what is behind it. If that is needed, the content of your dialog isnot sufficient

Comment: @Kukeltje, by minimizing a modal dialog, you get to see (again) what's behind w/o needing to close the dialog? Otherwise, you will have to close the dialog to even see what's in the main window. This is particularly painful if the modal dialog contains editable fields where "closing" the dialog has a special meaning. In this case, a minimizable modal dialog would be handy.

Comment: But WHY would you like to see behind the modal dialog in the first place. I you need some info, you need to make that visible (read-only) in the dialog to.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/minMax.xhtml) itself using Chrome 42. Please provide a MCVE along with all version+browser information.

Comment: @BalusC my apologies for not knowing it, but does the xhtml in showcase allow itself to be edited? I mean the content is editable, but once I click outside of the code content, the old code is restored. Can I really change the examples there and check if the change worked like a live demo?! If so, that will help me produce a MCVE easily, so just asking.

Comment: Ah OK, thus you can't reproduce it either? Then you really need to provide a MCVE. Here are some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info And no, there isn't a live editor over there.

Comment: @BalusC, I've now added an MCVE and the version information to the OP.

Comment: So PrimeFaces Extensions and PrimeFaces Theme are required in order to reproduce the problem? In other words, when you remove them both, then the problem disappears?

Comment: @BalusC I took out the extensions and the problem still persisted. I kept the Themes though - that's where the `theme.css` was imported from. Anyway, it looks like [someone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16579196/934307) faced this earlier and as expected the fix happens to be about the `z-order`. Not the prettiest solution, but works for now for me.